# Play scala template syntax for a string

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to drive the href attribute of this html anchor tag using a scala parameter and can't seem to get it to work.

```
@{
    val key = p.getKey()
    if(key == "facebook") {
     <a href="/authenticate/@(key)">Sign in with facebook</a>
    } else if (key == "twitter"){
     <a href="/authenticate/{key}">
        <span>Sign in with twitter {key} (this works)</span>
     </a>
    }    
}
```

In both examples the href attribute is not generating properly, but when I use {key} in the span tag that is outside of the html attribute, it prints out the key properly.

Comment: Did you try `@{key}`? You're using parentheses in the first `href` example, and no `@` in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twirl doesn't have support for [else-if](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/33). Since that caused you problems you wrapped it in a dynamic block `@{}`, which you can make work I think (never tried it). However this is not how things are usually done, it's preferred to use pattern matching instead.

Here is how your code could look like:

```
@p.getKey() match {
    case "facebook" => {
        <a href="/authenticate/@{p.getKey()}">Sign in with facebook</a>
    }
    case "twitter" => {
        <a href="/authenticate/@{p.getKey()}">
            <span>Sign in with twitter - key @{p.getKey()} </span>
        </a>
    }
}
```

Now that works, however you can also define reusable scoped values with [defining](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-values) (instead of vals) to cut down on the duplication of `p.getKey` and the href itself:

```
@defining(p.getKey()) { key =>
    @defining(s"/authentication/$key") { href =>
        @key match {
            case "facebook" => {
                <a href="@href">Sign in with facebook</a>
            }
            case "twitter" => {
                <a href="@href"> <span>Sign in with twitter - key @key</span> </a>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When assuming that the message is all the same except for the key it gets even easier, scrap the pattern matching and the href defining (since its used just once):

```
@defining(p.getKey()) { key =>
    <a href="/authentication/@key">Sign in with @key</a>
}
```